# CDI and JavaFX (javafx-weaver) Integration

Tags: javafx, cdi

After reading some articles about the CDI and Java FX integration, and the source codes of [javafx-weaver spring integration](https://github.com/rgielen/javafx-weaver/tree/master/spring).

I decided to add CDI integration to Java FX via the existing [javafx-weaver](https://github.com/rgielen/javafx-weaver) work to simplify the integration work.

The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/hantsy/cargotracker-regapp/tree/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/cargotrakcer/regapp/cdi).

I added a simple producer to expose `FxWeaver` to the CDI context.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class FxWeaverProducer {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(FxWeaverProducer.class.getName());

    @Produces
    FxWeaver fxWeaver(CDIControllerFactory callback) {
        var fxWeaver = new FxWeaver((Callback<Class<?>, Object>) callback,
                () -> LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "calling FxWeaver shutdown hook")
        );

        return fxWeaver;
    }

    public void destroyFxWeaver(@Disposes FxWeaver fxWeaver) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "destroying FxWeaver bean...");
        fxWeaver.shutdown();
    }
}
```

The problem is when using `fxWeaver.loadView` to load view, the controller [did not work as expected](https://github.com/hantsy/cargotracker-regapp/issues/2).

```java
@ApplicationScoped
@FxmlView("HandlingReport.fxml")
public class HandlingReportController {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(HandlingReportController.class.getName());

    @Inject
    private HandlingReportService handlingReportService;

    //fxml properties...

    @FXML 
    private void onSubmit(){...}
}
```

As above codes,  the dependent service `handlingReportService` in the controller class is null(not injected) when performing an action like `onSubmit`, it seems when JavaFX handles the `@FXML` properties binding it always used java reflection API.

If I change the method to `public void onSubmit()`( use `public` modifier), all FX fields become null when pressing the `onSubmit` button.

Any idea to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marked the controller class as `@Dependent`scope to resolve the problem.

```java
@Dependent
public class HandlingReportController { ...}
```